# Как загрузить файл с FTP сервера к себе на ПК

Tags: java, сервер, ftp

Я столкнулся с такой проблемой, что не получается реализовать загрузку файла с FTP сервера на свой ПК через java. Я использую библиотеку commons-net для FTPClient. Итак, я имею такой код:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
        FileInputStream fis = null;


        try {
            client.connect(server);
            client.login(user, password);
            client.enterRemotePassiveMode();
            client.setFileType(FTPClient.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);

            //
            // Create an InputStream of the file to be uploaded
            //
            String filename = "majesticSoft.png";


            //
            // Store file to server
            //
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\User\\IdeaProjects\\" + filename);
            boolean isDownloaded = client.retrieveFile("/resources/" + filename, fileOutputStream);
            if(!isDownloaded) {
                throw new Exception(client.getReplyString());               }
            fileOutputStream.flush();

            fileOutputStream.close();
            client.logout();
            client.disconnect();
            client.logout();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        } finally {
            try {
                if (fis != null) {
                    fis.close();
                }
                client.disconnect();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Но при запуске кода получаю ошибку:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Exception: 200 TYPE is now 8-bit binary
```

Что не так, я не понимаю. Прошу помочь и объяснить ошибку. Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Вы используете пассивный режим FTP. Скорее всего, на удаленном сервере стоит брандмауэр, который динамически выделяет порты. Порты для пассивного режима - перекрыты.

Уберите строку:

```
 client.enterRemotePassiveMode();
```

и попробуйте активный режим.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Я пробовал уже функцию enterRemoteActiveMode(server, port). По итогу выходила SocketException